# Delphi FireDac + Oracle without Oracle Client Instalation

Tags: oracle, delphi, firedac

Is there any way I can connect my Delphi application (FireDac) to an Oracle database directly?

Currently I can make the connection, but I need to install Oracle Client

on the embarcadero site (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Connect_to_Oracle_Server_(FireDAC)) only shows how to connect to the installed client.

I generated a demo that connects using host, port and instance name.

on the machine that the installed client works perfect. 
already in the machine that does not have the client, even with all the dll, does not connect, presenting the following error:

[FireDAC] [Phys] [Ora] -1309. OCI is not properly installed on this machine (NOE1 / INIT).

even the dll oci.dll being in the same directory as the application,

follows code for connection:

```
procedure TForm1.btnConectarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   conDados.Close;
   conDados.Params.DriverID := 'Ora';
   conDados.Params.Database := '(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.xxx)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = SMARTSRV)))';
   conDados.Params.UserName := 'xxxxx';
   conDados.Params.Password := 'xxxxx';
   conDados.Open();
end;
```

Another setting that did not work either

```
   conDados.Close;
   // conDados.Params.DriverID := 'Ora';
   // conDados.Params.Database := '(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.xxx)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = xxx)))';
   // conDados.Params.UserName := 'xxx';
   // conDados.Params.Password := 'xxx';
   conDados.Params.DriverID := 'Ora';
   conDados.Params.Database := '192.168.0.xxx:1521/xxx';
   conDados.Params.Values['OSAuthent'] := 'No';
   conDados.Params.UserName := 'xxx';
   conDados.Params.Password := 'xxx';
   conDados.Params.Values['CharacterSet'] := 'UTF8';
   odlDados.DriverID := 'Ora';
   odlDados.NLSLang := 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1';
   odlDados.VendorHome := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
   odlDados.VendorLib := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'oci.dll';
   conDados.Open();
```

Is there any way I can connect my Delphi application (FireDac) to an Oracle database directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after other attempts, we find that the error is generated by the msvcr120.dll dll, but it is not described in the error.

we installed the following microsoft software and everything worked correctly.

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Comment: Doesn't work for me unless I have the client installed. Are you also installing other files (you mention putting the OCI.dll in the same folder)?

Answer (score 3):

The full Oracle Client has indeed a huge footprint (hunderths of MB), and expects to be installed before the application.

You can use the [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html) alternative. It is a cut-down version, giving access to only the OCI library/dll (for the *Basic Light* edition), which requires no installation: just copy the dlls with your exe. It is supported by Oracle, gives high performance and best stability. We don't fully trust "direct TCP connection" clients written in pascal, which save a few MB, but are not certified by Oracle - if a lot of money is paid for using Oracle, you can afford the few MB of disk storage to have a 100% Oracle connection chain.

This is what we use with our [Open Source SynDBOracle](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_117) library, but [FireDAC also officially supports it](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Connect_to_Oracle_Server_(FireDAC)).

If you want to reduce the client footprint even more, consider switching from RAD to a REST architecture, and keep the Oracle connection on your application service side. Plain HTTPS + JSON will require no library whatsoever on the client side, easy scale to thousands of simultaneous connections (with the proper framework), and allow even JavaScript clients. Worth a direction to look into.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but even extracting all the files into the EXE folder, adding the directory to the PATH environment variable and creating the ORACLE_HOME environment variable the error remains the same ([FireDAC] [Phys] [Ora] -314. Can not load vendor library [C: \ Users \ xxxx \ Desktop \ testOracle \ oci.dll] Hint: check it in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has x86 bitness. According to the site of the embarcadero, they say that they have to install the client. I will accept your response, because I believe you do not have much to do, thank you

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the correct DLL? Download 32-bit version for Win32 Delphi target, and 64-bit version for Win64 Delphi target.

Comment: yes, I'm sure, I downloaded it from here: (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) both version 18.5.0.0.0 and version 12.2.0.1.0, and the two presented the same problem

Comment: Don't forget both instant clients also require visual studio redistributes to be installed - read the install instructions at the bottom of the download page.

Comment: @Brian It is installed, as you mentioned, we also saw this in the installation manual, and even with it installed, the error continues.

Comment: @Passella The only other thing would be random remains of other oracle clients leading it astray. Use a FDPhysOracleDriverLink and reference the driver DLL directly (OCI.DLL) in the VendorLib property.

Comment: @Brian, It's already like this: odlDados.VendorHome := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
   odlDados.VendorLib := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'oci.dll';

Answer (score 2):

For this you will ne to use proper database driver that does not require use of Oracle Client.

Luckily dbExpress provides a suitable driver for accessing Oracle databases directly through TCP/IP without Oracle Client

https://www.devart.com/dbx/oracle/

But dbExpress isn't for free and will thus increase the cost of developing of your application.

Comment: Don't you mean DevArt, not dbExpress?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as you yourself said, it's not free, and it's out of the question

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if you already solve it, but I've noticed that you forgot to setup the **tnsnames.ora** file.

Something similiar to this:

```
#ALIAS# =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = #ORACLE_IP#)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = #SERVICE#)
    )
  )
```

Replace the values with **##** by your oracle configuration and save the file in the same directory of instant client.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Enterprise Connectors (based on FireDAC)? 
https://www.embarcadero.com/products/enterprise-connectors/enterprise-connectors

Here is more information on the Oracle connector: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/oracledb/firedac/

Answer (score 1):

please tell me you install oracle client 32 bit or 64 bit.which option do you install oracle client(administrator, runtime, instant client, custom)

i use win 7 64 bit, oracle database 18c,rad studio delphi 10.3 in the same computer.

i just install oracle client win 64 bit.but still get that error [FireDAC] [Phys] [Ora] -1309. OCI is not properly installed on this machine (NOE1 / INIT).

Comment: The question is how to run the application without installing Oracle client, I'm not sure, but if I'm not mistaken, we installed as an administrator, but there are more things that I will not know to answer

Answer (score 0):

FireDAC can't be connected to Oracle without Oracle Client Installation. As far as I know, only components from Devart - ODAC and UniDAC - can do this.

You can read their documentation on how to connect to Oracle using only the Host, Port, and Instance Name. In their documentation, the connection without using Oracle Client Installation is called Direct mode.